# Хранение функции

Tags: c++, dll

Есть указатель на функцию, расположенную в *DLL* библиотеке. Можно ли эту функцию сохранить в объекте типа `std::function<...>` при корректном указании шаблонных параметров, затем отключить библиотеку через `FreeLibrary` (работаю в *MSVC*) и работать с функцией через `std::function`? Мне просто надо запихать туда разыменованный указатель на эту функцию?

Comment: Вам скорее надо иметь LIB статичную библиотеку для включения в тело программы. Тогда не понадобится FreeLibrary и др.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.е., простыми словами, что вы хотите сделать (вернее, что у вас получится) - вы сохраняете указатель на функцию, выбрасываете из памяти *код* функции, оставляя указатель непонятно куда, и вызываете ее...
Как вы думаете, что у вас получится?

`std::function` *тело* функции никоим образом не сохраняет. Ну, а *указатель* на функцию будет инвалидирован вызовом `FreeLibrary`.

Набросать соответствующий код очень просто, можете убедиться сами...

**indll.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) inDll()
{
    cout << "From DLL\n";
}
```

Компилируем как `cl /LD indll.cpp`

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    HMODULE dll;
    if (0 != (dll = LoadLibrary("inDll.dll")))
    {
        cout << "Load success\n";

        FARPROC ptr = GetProcAddress(dll,"inDll");
        function<void(void)> f = ptr;
        f();
        FreeLibrary(dll);

    }
}
```

Компилируем как `cl test.cpp`

Запускаем `test.exe`, убеждаемся, что все работает. Меняем местами строки

```
        f();
        FreeLibrary(dll);
```

компилируем и убеждаемся окончательно, что так поступать нельзя :)

Answer (score 4):

Ни в языке С, ни в языке С++ нет понятия "сохранить функцию". Любые манипуляции с `std::function` или чем-то подобным будут работать только и именно с *указателем* на оригинальную функцию.

С "разыменованным указателем на функцию" в С++ можно сделать только весьма ограниченное количество вещей: например, вызвать функцию или преобразовать его обратно в указатель. "Запихать" результат разыменования никуда нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` является лишь обёрткой над некоторой сущностью, которую можно *вызвать*. Если код этой сущности становится недоступен (например, после выполнения `FreeLibrary`), то попытки вызвать его будут приводить к неопределённому поведению. Скорее всего Вы просто получите некоторую ошибку времени выполнения от операционной системы.

Не стоит считать `std::function` каким-то волшебным контейнером, который хранит код, и если его куда-то передать, то он может быть выполнен. Иначе можно было бы развить мысль и предположить, что, скажем, упаковка и передача объекта `std::function` по сети на другое устройство будет допускать возможность выполнить код, "хранимый" в этом объекте. Такое невозможно хотя бы по причине того, что на другом конце сети может быть устройство совершенно иной архитектуры и код (грубо говоря, последовательность команд) должен быть совсем иным. Для обеспечения подобного используются другие технологии, например, [CORBA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA).